# Using CSF (or other app) to block access to tomcat manager based on URL and ip address

Tags: linux, tomcat, firewall

I am using CSF on my linux VPS. I want to restrict access to the tomcat manager based on if an ip other than my home ip (my home ip is in the csf.allow file) tries to reach the tomcat manager. In CSF (or perhaps some other application), is there a way to limit access based on url entered like `myserverip/manager*` so that no other ip than my home ip can make a request to such url?

I dont want to block the tomcat port since that's where I have a web application running and would like it to be publicly accessible.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: My mistake. I requested it to be moved as instructed. Thanks